# Build Error - CustomerManagement-AutoViews

Tags: mvvmcross

I downloaded the project sample `CustomerManagement-AutoViews` from this [location](https://github.com/ataparia/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20CustomerManagement/CustomerManagement%20-%20AutoViews).

After performing the necessary setup mentioned on the same url to build the solution, I still get a bunch of error related to resource not found when I build the project.

All the error description says

> CustomerManagement.AutoViews.Droid.Resource.Layout' does not contain a
>   definition for
>   'dialog_textfieldright'   C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\MvvmCross-Tutorials\Sample
>   - CustomerManagement\CustomerManagement - AutoViews\CustomerManagement.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs   70  127 CustomerManagement.AutoViews.Droid

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does the original slodge copy of the repo work for you?

Comment: I don't think so Stuart. I thought there might be some problem with the code that I got from the repo. I deleted the repo, forked the branch again but still having the same issue.